# Custom metric for Semantic segmentation

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a multi-class semantic segmentation task, and would like to define a custom, weighted metric for calculating how well my NN is performing.

I am using U-net to segment my image into one of 8 classes, of which 1-7 are the particular classes and 0 is background. How do I use the standard custom metric template defined on the [Keras metrics](https://keras.io/metrics/) page, so that I only get the IoU of only channels 1-7, multiplied by a (1,7) weights array? I tried removing the background channel in the custom metric by using

```
y_true, y_pred = y_true[1:,:,:], y_pred[1:, :,:]
```

but it does not look like that's what I want. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change that was necessary

```
def dice_coef_multilabel(y_true, y_pred, numLabels=CLASSES):
    dice=0
    for index in range(numLabels):
        dice -= dice_coef(y_true[:,:,index], y_pred[:,:,index])
    return dice
```

If needed, the dice coeff can be calcualted across channels by using two nested loops to loop over all the channel combinations. I'm also including the dice coefficient calculation.

```
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
```

FWIW, [this github link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9395#issuecomment-379228094) has various types of metrics were implemented in a channel-wise manner.